# Time traveling teen gets lost in the stone age

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for a book I read when I was young on the recommendation of my father. While I read the book in the mid 90's I believe that it was published in the 60's or 70's.

It is about a teen who finds a time machine in his (I think..) grandfathers basement and accidentally time travels back to the stone age. He wonders off from the machine and gets lost. He finds a group of cavemen who he eventually joins and survives with. He slowly grows up and they become a substitute family. At the end of the book he finds the time machine again and returns to the date he left but now a man very different from when he left.

It was written in English and I have a strong feeling that the title was short, one or two words, perhaps relating to either time travel or cavemen. I was around 13 or so at the time and the book was available in the middle school library. I have not found any books that come close to this description as I know the main character was a solitary boy. Most books I have encountered are about multiple travelers.

I'm guessing that it was not a very popular book as I have been searching for the title on and off for a number of years now. As this book was recommended to me, I've often thought of sharing it with my own kids.

Comment: Was it written in English? Do you remember any details, like names, book cover etc? Are there any time machine books you've ruled out already?

Comment: It was written in English and I have a strong feeling that the title was short, one or two words, perhaps relating to either time travel or cavemen. I was around 13 or so at the time and the book was available in the middle school library. I have not found any books that come close to this description as I know the main character was a solitary boy. Most books I have encountered are about multiple travelers.

Answer (score 2):

This book is by [Chad Oliver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chad_Oliver).

This book is called *Mists of Time* and is by Chad Oliver.  It was published in the 50's.  I read it in secondary school and I have never forgotten it.  The young boy is called Mark and the time machine is his uncle's.

Comment: I wonder if you are combining two titles into one: [*The Mists of Dawn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mists_of_Dawn) and *The Winds of Time*, both published in the 1950s.

Comment: @Tsundoku Not *The Winds of Time*, no teens and no time travel in that one, see description in this scifi.SE Q&A: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231387/1950s-pulp-sci-fi-hibernating-alien-traps-fly-fisherman-in-a-mountain-cave. Must be *The Mists of Dawn*.